# Access Map via Variable Name in Path Name

Tags: javascript

I have a map object containing a list of data about people. Every person's name is unique. The data fields of each person may not contain the same type of information (ie - Joey contains a date field, but Jill does not).

I am wondering if I can access a certain part of my map by using a variable name as part of the map path. Consider the following:

```
var data = {
  'Joey': {
    'id': '912',
    'date': 'May 14 2012',
  },
  'Jill': {
    'id': '231',
    'login': 'JillM',
  }
}

var name="Joey";
var joeyDate = data. + name + .date; //This does not work. Is there an alternative?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
data[name]["date"]
```

This is an alternative to `data.Joey`, which should also work, but is static.

You can also use:

```
data[name].date
```

The difference is exactly what you're inquiring about - `[]` notation is better for dynamic retrieval and possibly invalid keys that wouldn't be allowed with Javascript if using dot notation. For example, if you had a key of "date-born", you can't use `data[name].date-born`, but you can use `data[name]["date-born"]`.

An example of using this is:

```
for (name in data) {
    console.log(data[name].date);
}
```

But of course, `date` must be a property (where it isn't for "Jill"), otherwise `undefined` will be returned.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I am looking for. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way: `mapName.get(keyName).propertyName`

In your case: `data.get(name).date`